# PHP - Amazon S3 - tpyo, can't upload from ubuntu server but works fine on local

Tags: php, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, upload

I want user to upload an image via a form, then store it in a temporary folder to resize and convert it. After the image is converted, it can be uploaded to Amazon S3 server (I'm using tpyo S3). 
The code works perfectly fine on local machine, but when it runs on my Ubuntu EC2 server, the image wont upload (even though it's converted). I tried different folder permission settings but nothing changed
This is my code:

```
    $dir = "/var/www/html/inventorymanager/imageupload/";

    //path to new file location
    $moved_file = $dir.$uploadedFileName;
    if(move_uploaded_file($tmpUploadedFile, $moved_file)) {
        chmod($moved_file, 0775);
    } else{
        echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
    }

    //amazon file to upload name: create random name for the file to upload to S3 server
    $amazonFileToUploadName = randomStringGen(30).".jpg";
    //upload resized image to S3 server
    S3::putObject(S3::inputFile($moved_file, false), "inventorymanager-huyvu",  $amazonFileToUploadName, S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ);

    //delete processed file after it is uploaded
    unlink($moved_file);
```

Comment: You don't need to move the file before uploading to s3, you can upload it directly.

Comment: Because I want to resize and convert the image to a different format. Somehow, the static function won't work on remote server, yet it's been working perfectly fine on my local machine.

Comment: There are probably errors that are being suppressed on the remote environment. There is likely a permission issue of some kind. You can use `tempnam` to generate temp files in `/tmp` which should get around the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Hah. I just found the solution after spending 10 hours debugging the code and trying different methods to upload. I later found out that my server had not had CURL installed! This S3 tpyo class only works with CURL installed. Hope this would help someone's time